# Enzyme shallow rendering child components, behavior change on package upgrade

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am currently working to upgrade the npm dependencies for a project I own and have hit a number of broken test cases because the shallow rendering behavior of components has changed.

I have migrated the react/enzyme/jest dependencies from

```
"react": "15.6.1",
"enzyme": "3.3.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-15": "1.0.5",
"jest": "23.6.0",
```

to

```
"react": "16.8.6",
"enzyme": "3.10.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.14.0"
"jest": "24.8.0",
```

In the previous combination the following test succeeds:

```
describe("TpidTenantList", () => {
    it("test components", () => {
        const Foo = props => <div className="Foo" />;
        const Bar = props => (
            <div className="Bar">
                <Foo />
                <Foo />
            </div>
        );

        const wrapper = shallow(<Bar />);
        expect(wrapper.find(Foo).length).toBe(2);
    });
});
```

However, with the new combination this test fails.  Looking at the rendered html for the wrapper, I can see that shallow has actually rendered the Foo subcomponent, yielding

```
<div class="Bar">
    <div class="Foo"></div>
    <div class="Foo"></div>
</div>
```

If I change the test to `.find(".Foo")` instead, the test passes, however, some of the components being tested contain HighChart and other libraries which are problematic to render.

I have tried wrapping the component under test, as well as providing the `disableLifecycleMethods` option to shallow, but the full component tree seems to be rendering.

Ideally I'd like to coerce the behavior to that of the old combinations library, or, if there is a preferred pattern, I'd be happy to adopt that.

Comment: Not sure how the previous version worked, but on the most recent release you need to use a CSS-style selector as an argument to ```find```, e.g. ```find(".Foo")```.

Comment: I had a typo in the example which I have edited to fix, in the previous version the component type, `Foo` was working as a selector.  Using `".Foo"` as a selector now works, but only because the call to shallow is rendering the subcomponents.

Comment: Ah, finding components should still work.  Have you tried ```expect(wrapper.find(Foo)).to.have.lengthOf(3);```